# How do I add an "Add Favorite" link to my mobile site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, mobile-website

I'm building a mobile site and the client wants users to be able to click a link on the site that adds a link to the site to the user's home screen on their phone.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible. Many browsers allow this functionality.

You need to use the Browser's API to add that link to the user's home screen. Otherwise using the HTML or JS it is not possible.

I hope you're talking the way Chrome adds a hyperlink to the screen, then you need to learn how the browser does so. For that please read the dev documentations. Their is no such option in HTML, you need to learn the OS dev docs and as well as Browser documentation.

Google Chrome:

https://developers.google.com/chrome/mobile/docs/installtohomescreen

Comment: Unless you have specific instructions on how to perform the task, this is really a comment and not an answer.

Comment: So, there's not a cross browser solution?

Comment: I don't think there is a solution that would be implemented to all the browsers and OSs...